# Retrieve Youtube Comments OAuth 2.0

Tags: youtube-api

I try to download Youtube video comments based on video ID. I checked the API sample code that it uses OAuth 2.0. However I only need to download the comments but not modify them. Do I still need OAuth 2.0 or just API Key?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go through `OAuth` if you're only retrieving comments. You can make the request with only your API key over HTTP and receive a JSON response in return.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId={yourVideoId}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

More info can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads#resource-representation)

Comment: Hmm.Is there any JSON tutorials/sample using Youtube API? I use Python to write the code. Not sure how exactly use GET etc. Thanks!

Comment: I actually fixed it. I need to use build() to get the video response.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get comments using https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list then just the API key is needed.

Comment: Thanks! The sample code still uses OAuth 2.0. How should I retrieve the page? Like import API library something instead of those in the sample code: from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets